# What is the difference between assigning my object or setting the value in it

Tags: java

I'm working with Java and JSF on a Wildfly server.
I have a remote EJB where a function modifies an object from a Bean.

What is the difference between these 2?
Assigning the object

```
public void updateStatus() {
    for (TCSInstance i : tcsInstanceObjects) {          
        i = tcsClient.updateServerStatus(i);
    }
}
```

Setting the values

```
public void updateStatus() {
    for (TCSInstance i : tcsInstanceObjects) {          
        TCSInstance obj = tcsClient.updateServerStatus(i);
        i.setStatus(obj.getStatus());
        i.setVersion(obj.getVersion());
    }
}
```

updateServerStatus Function in my remote EJB

```
   public TCSInstance updateServerStatus(TCSInstance tcsInstanceObject) {
        List<String> returnValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        String pattern = ".*(\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}).*";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        if (connect(tcsInstanceObject.host, tcsInstanceObject.port)) {
            returnValues = readFromServer(stopValueBeforeLog);
            tcsInstanceObject.setStatus("Active");

            Matcher m = p.matcher(returnValues.toString());
            if (m.find()) {
                tcsInstanceObject.setVersion(m.group(1));
            } else {
                tcsInstanceObject.setVersion(returnValues.toString());
            }
            disconnect();
        } else {
            tcsInstanceObject.setStatus("Not Active");
        }     

        return tcsInstanceObject;
    }
```

As you can see I'm setting the Version and Status in the EJB and then return the object.

Option 1 assigning doesn't work.
Version and Status is undefined.

Option 2 works perfectly.

But why ? Can somebody tell me please ?

EDIT
TCSInstance class

```
package com.six_group.dsx.tat.tcs.web.data;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class TCSInstance implements Serializable {
    public String env;
    public String host;
    public int    port;
    public String dir;
    public String version;
    public String status;

    public TCSInstance(String _env, String _host, String _port, String _dir, String _version) {
        this.env = _env;
        this.host = _host;
        this.port = Integer.parseInt(_port);
        this.dir = _dir;
        this.version = _version;
        this.status = null;
    }

    public TCSInstance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getEnv() {
        return env;
    }

    public void setEnv(String env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public String getDir() {
        return dir;
    }

    public void setDir(String dir) {
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any treatement in `getStatus()` and `getVerison()` methods in `TCSInstance` class.

Comment: The line `i = tcsClient.updateServerStatus(i);` looks very weird to me.

Comment: @andolsizied No I just return the value

Comment: coudl you share your `TCSInstance ` class.

Comment: @andolsizied I added it as edit, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this

```
i = tcsClient.updateServerStatus(i);
```

you do not assign the object, you assign a variable. The variable before the assignment references one object; after the assignment it references another object. Unless you use the variable after the assignment, the assignment has no effect.

On the other hand, when you set object's properties, you change the existing object, so you see the effect.

If you want to replace an object with a different one, which is necessary when your objects are *immutable*, you would need to modify the collection in which your objects are stored (i.e. `tcsInstanceObjects`). However, you need to be careful, because modifications to collections being iterated are not allowed. You would need to use an iterator to do it correctly.

> if I modify the functions and add the whole `TCSInstanceObjects` list as a parameter instead of one object from the list, it works. If I iterate over the List in `updateServerStatus()` and then return the whole
>
> ```
> list: tcsInstanceObjects = tcsClient.updateServerStatus(tcsInstanceObjects);
> ```
>
> What is the difference ?

That is exactly the situation that I describe above: you start with a container that has one set of objects, then you make another container that has the modified set of objects, and finally you replace the old container with the new container. That's why everything works correctly.

Comment: @andolsizied In the code that you posted in response to my other answer  `updatePerson` method was doing all the work. You can replace {person = updatePerson(person);} with {updatePerson(person);} and everything will continue working. In other words, the assignment is completely irrelevant; you rewrote OP's snippet #2, not snippet #1.